# Compare an object's value with the value of enum

Tags: java, enums

I declare `enum` with a value assigned to each of them.

```
public enum RATING {
   G(0), P(12), M(16);
   private int age;

   private RATING(int age){
   this.age = age;
   }
}
```

I want to do something like this, but it doesn't compile.

```
... if (Customer.getAge() >= Film.getRating()) ...
```

`Customer.getAge()` returns an `int`;
`Film.getRating()` returns a `enum RATING`

How can I compare an object's value with the value of `enum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following method to RATING:

```
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
```

And then you can use the following line:

```
if (Customer.getAge() >= Film.getRating().getAge())
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. But why I can't do `Film.getRating().values()` instead?

Comment: @Matt you don't have a values method.

Comment: Why I am asking this because I looked through the JavaDoc - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html.

Comment: In the middle part there is - For example, they have a static `values` method that returns an array containing all of the values of the enum in the order they are declared

Comment: At that point, you get the value of every enum, not of the one you want to compare against.

Comment: Of course you have a `values` method. It returns an array of _all the enum constants you've defined_. So in this case, `Film.getRating().values()` returns `{G, P, M}`. Not exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

At this point, you are not comparing it to the value of the enum, but with the enum itself.

Change your enum like this:

```
public enum RATING {
   G(0), P(12), M(16);
   private int age;

   private RATING(int age){
   this.age = age;
   }

   public int getAge(){
    return this.age;
    }
}
```

and compare like this:

```
if (Customer.getAge() >= Film.getRating().getAge())
```

Answer (score 2):

Add to your enum this method

```
 public int getAge(){
   return age;
   }
```

and modify the code

```
if (Customer.getAge() >= Film.getRating().getAge()) ..
```